# $httpBackend prevents normal angular routing; how do I configure $httpBackend to allow normal routing behavior?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I need to load up $httpBackend in order to mock out $http server calls (which return JSON).  I've defined my own mocks, but when I load up my angular app with $httpBackend and my own mocks, I get an error: "Unexpected GET request: pages/main.html."  Now main.html is my main page; when a user goes to my app, this is the first page they see.  I've looked at [the docs for $httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend), but it doesn't mention how to set up $httpBackend to allow normal routing behavior.  I can't find anything in stack overflow about this topic, either.  [A google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/Vbg6j2qW_qc) suggests using a method 'passThrough()', but whenever I implement this method, I get an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'passThrough'" so I'm at a loss.

Does anyone know how to set up $httpBackend to allow normal routing behavior?

Comment: Did you inject httpBackend properly? When I inject it in myAppDev and then use it in myApp, I also get an error like this.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @jenso well... no, but it's on my to-do list before I get a experienced and respected dev to look at my project.  If you resolve this, please let me know?  If I don't hear back from you, I'll take this task up in about 2 weeks.

Answer (score 3):

## This is how I've solved it

```
var app = angular.module('App');

app.run(function($httpBackend) {

  var mockData = {
    "id":"492",
    "title":"Agreement",
   };

  // respond with mockdata on all request for /api/frontend/*
  $httpBackend.whenGET(/\/api\/frontend\//).respond(mockData); 

  // pass trough all GET requests to api/backend and so on, that havent been catched
  // in another $httpBackend.whenGET rule
  $httpBackend.whenGET().passThrough();
});
```